# Allocate more resources to QEMU from CLI?

Tags: resources, qemu

### Context

After installing and running a virtual machine of Ubuntu 22.04 in Qemu, using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm
cd ~/Downloads
qemu-img create ubuntu22.img 20G
qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -m 1024 -machine smm=off -cdrom ~/Downloads/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso -boot order=d ubuntu22.img
```

I can run the vm with:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -m 1024 -machine smm=off -boot order=d ubuntu22_clean0.img -smp 4
```

### Issue

However, it is still quite slow and unstable and hangs whilst the host machine does not have any performance issues at all. Hence I would like to allocate more resources from the host to the Qemu VM, I am not yet sure what is the bottleneck, CPU usage, RAM (or something else) I assume it is not disk space, since there is still 100+gb free space.

Hence I would like to ask:

### Question

*How can I allocate more resources, ram and/or processing power to Ubuntu 22.04 on Qemu, from the CLI?*

### Ram

In [this documentation](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/qemu-manpage.html) I found the `-m` argument allows specification of the amount of ram that is given to the device, increasing it improved its stability.

### CPU

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/390941/how-do-i-use-the-cpu-option-in-qemu) gives an example on how one can specify which CPU to use. I expect specifying which CPU to use, may improve the performance. However I did not yet find a generic method to identify which CPU is on the device and which of the listed CPU's to pick accordingly.